# php string date return wrong date

Tags: php

My code:

```
   echo "Strtotime : ";

   echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('9 March, 2015'));

   echo "<br> mktime :  ";

   echo date("Y-m-d",mktime('9 March, 2015'));

   echo "<br> Normal :  ";

   echo date("Y-m-d",'9 March, 2015');
```

I need output 2015-03-09

Comment: Where does the string `9 March, 2015` come from - do you have any control over this, what other formats might you be receiving?

Comment: Please try looking at the manual for [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) Its nothing like your attempt at using it

Comment: Also look at the manual for [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) If you use the functions correctly they will work correctly

Comment: Better check the manual for [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as well as you are about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the DateTime class for this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat ("d M, Y", "9 march, 2015");
echo $date->format ("Y-m-d");
```

If you check the [PHP manual for DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can get a whole lot of other really good tips on how to further take advantage of this class. Which makes working with dates in PHP a lot easier than with the old functions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime with date_create_from_format, if the structure of the String is always the same:

```
$d = '9 March, 2015';

echo date_create_from_format('d F, Y', $d)->format('Y-m-d');
```

See a running example: https://3v4l.org/s8EHi

Comment: Its Working Fine.....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show date - month - year you can apply this

```
<?php 
echo date('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this code to get exact date format.

$orig_date = "22/09/2016";

$date = str_replace ('/', '-', $orig_date);

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime ($date));

See more [date and time format example here](http://www.codefixup.com/changing-the-format-of-date-and-time-in-php)